# What is wlp2s0 and why is its state listed as disconnected?

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager

What is wlp2s0 and why is its state listed as disconnected?

```
user@userserver:/home/user# nmcli device status
DEVICE           TYPE       STATE         CONNECTION
wlp2s0           wifi       disconnected  --
br-1b52718df13e  bridge     unmanaged     --
br-b7876f6c8928  bridge     unmanaged     --
br-c0f0232c3b60  bridge     unmanaged     --
br-ddd8994cef1d  bridge     unmanaged     --
docker0          bridge     unmanaged     --
enp3s0           ethernet   unmanaged     --
lo               loopback   unmanaged     --
p2p-dev-wlp2s0   wifi-p2p   unmanaged     --
wg0              wireguard  unmanaged     --
```

Comment: Basic details as to what you're actually running (ie. Ubuntu product & what release of that product) should be provided. Please also include all details in your question (*details hidden in title may not be visible for all readers when viewing the page*).  You've tagged *network manager* which isn't included on all products, does your *unstated* system use it?

Comment: @guiverc "network-manager" is NetworkManager, the predominant daemon that manages networks on an average desktop Linux. It is part of Ubuntu Desktop's base installation.

Comment: But we're not told this is Ubuntu Desktop; [*Netplan.io*](https://netplan.io/) is the default for Ubuntu Server, and Server is mentioned in the provided paste.  @mcendu   (*there are numerous other causes; someone may have forced the port down, missing kernel modules (aka drivers) etc but we don't know the Ubuntu product/release details so cannot really speculate as to what options are available until we have details provided*)

Comment: @guiverc But I didn't see any explicit mentions of "Server" in the paste...

Comment: explicit no, we're given almost no details; but *userserver* as $HOSTNAME I saw as being two words; user.server

Answer (score 1):

`wlp2s0` is your 802.11 (a.k.a. Wi-Fi) adapter. You have not connected it to any access point.